# What do LC_TIME and LC_NUMERIC settings actually change in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, collation

According to the [PostgreSQL 9.5 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/locale.html), LC_TIME affects "Formatting of dates and times" and LC_NUMERIC - "Formatting of numbers", but I can't seem to see any difference from changing these.

For instance, I changed my postgresql.conf to this:

```
lc_messages = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_monetary = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_numeric = 'English_United States.1252'
lc_time = 'English_United States.1252'
```

then created a new DB and ran:

`SELECT current_date, format('Date: %s, Number: %s', current_date, 1234.6789);`

and got

```
2016-04-26     Date: 2016-04-26, Number: 1234.6789
```

I then tried the same with "French_France.1252" and "C" collations and got exactly the same results. (I restarted PostgreSQL in-between and verified the changes using `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name ~~ 'lc%'`)

So what difference are those settings *supposed* to make?

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.5.2 on Windows 7.